# WordPress Plugin Hook filter body_class

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to achieve that when the page attribute selects a certain template, the background color of the page can be randomly changed. (Only this page, not for all pages).

Unfortunately, my code (PHP) doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'body_class','modele_bg_couleur' );

function modele_bg_couleur($classes)
{
    if(is_page_template('modele-bg-couleur.php')){
        
        $test = array("beige", "azure", "linen", "snow");
        $classes[] = $test[array_rand($test)];
    }

    return $classes;
}
   
add_action( 'admin_head', 'modele_bg_couleur_css' );

function modele_bg_couleur_css(){
    echo "
    <style type='text/css'>
    .beige {
        background-color: beige;
    }
    .azure {
        background-color: azure;
    }
    .linen {
        background-color: linen;
    }
    .snow {
        background-color: snow;
    }
    </style>
    ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `body_class` filter lets you add classes to the front end of your site. The `admin_head` action lets you add custom code to the admin pages (Wordpress back end). So right now you are adding a body class to the front end of your site but applying the CSS to the back end.

I'm assuming you want this to work on your front end. You can then just add the following CSS to your theme via the customizer or via your own child theme:

```
body.beige { background-color: beige!important; }
body.azure { background-color: azure!important; }
body.linen { background-color: linen!important; }
body.snow { background-color: snow!important; }
```